# Is it possible to determine the Working Copy size before checkout?

Tags: svn

I would like to see if the working copy will fit onto my hard drive and don't want to waste time and bandwith.

So my question is: Is it possible to determine the size of the working copy before checkout?

I do have access to the repository, but its filesize does not say anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working copy will be a little larger than twice the size of the respective files in the repository, because it stored the pristine version of each in the `.svn` subdirectories.  (It stores other admin data too, like properties, but this should not amount to much.)

You want some way of listing the files in the repository (from the subtree you want to check out), with their size, and summing it up.  I do not think the `svn` command line tool does this directly, but it will do it for each file:

```
svn ls -v -R file:///d:/svn/edmund/fs/trunk

2891 edmund                Oct 23  2009 ./
2867 edmund            140 Aug 14  2009 Makefile
2883 Edmund          12869 Oct 15  2009 block.c
2883 Edmund           9817 Oct 15  2009 file.c
2883 Edmund           7572 Oct 15  2009 fs-internal.h
2884 edmund           6845 Oct 16  2009 fs.c
2891 edmund           1407 Oct 23  2009 fs.h
2891 edmund                Oct 23  2009 linux/
2867 edmund            208 Aug 14  2009 linux/Makefile
2891 edmund           6684 Oct 23  2009 linux/main.c
2882 edmund           4822 Oct 15  2009 notes.txt
2891 edmund           7408 Oct 23  2009 operations.c
2891 edmund           3834 Oct 23  2009 special.c
2880 edmund                Oct 01  2009 test/
2869 edmund            695 Aug 16  2009 test/Makefile
2880 edmund          11220 Oct 01  2009 test/operations-test.c
2877 edmund           3826 Aug 20  2009 test/tree-test.c
2883 Edmund          23413 Oct 15  2009 tree.c
2883 Edmund                Oct 15  2009 win/
2883 Edmund          28590 Oct 15  2009 win/main.c
```

You could sum these manually, or pipe to a scriptlet that will sum all the values in columns 12-26 (e.g.).

Comment: This will tell you how big each file is, but an actual checkout will take more space than the simple sum of the file sizes, because file systems allocate blocks in fixed units that waste some space for each file. If you know your file system block size, I guess you could calculate for that as well. You could account for directory creation as well.

Comment: If your repository contains any externals links, a checkout will traverse that content as well. Therefore you would need to add that into the summing. svn propget -R svn:externals [URL]

Answer (score 1):

Using TortoiseSVN I can see the size of files in the repo. but not of directories.  That might help.

Answer (score 1):

Because of my reputation I cannot comment Edmund's answer.

I usually use below pipe to calculate the size of content in some path (in this case trunk/project) on our Subversion server:

```
svn ls -vR file:///path/to/repo/trunk/project | awk '{if ($3 != "") sum+=$3; i++} END {printf "\n%s: %.0f\n%s: %.0f %s","files qty",i,"wc size",sum/1024/1024/1024,"GB"}'
```

But in case of a working copy you must also include the size of the .svn directory that a checkout will also produce. In my case a fresh working copy puts twice that much to .svn. So for 10GB of content I plan 20GB of disk space for a working copy plus some for future needs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know the size before hand.
If you know someone who has checked it out then you could ask them..